# How to trace a node.js dependency?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I found some code on this site that works well, it does this:

```
process.stdin.pipe(require('split')()).on('data', function(line) {
  ...
```

Curiously no `split` npm package is installed locally or globally. I search and can't find such a package in official node.js docs.

So I'm curious about where to find information about it. Sure, there's a `split` npm package that exists, and it does support what my code seems to be doing with it, but... the dots don't connect, because I never had to `npm install` it!

How do I figure out where the javascript source code for split is on my system? Maybe `split` has somehow been "included" in the "standard" node.js library and the documentation just needs to catch up?

Additional info:

```
$ node
> require ('split')
[Function: split]
> process.version
'v6.9.2'
>
```

I realize now that `npm ls` shows `split` exists deep in the dependencies in this project. So that is probably where it is being pulled in from.

Comment: opening up a fresh node.js terminal results in an exception when `require('split')` - so this would indicate there is nothing in the library. Have you debugged and see where you step into on that one? I'm guessing [this npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/split) is installed on your end

Comment: @scniro Yeah i didn't really realize that `require` will fetch something from deep inside the dependency hierarchy in a npm project.

Comment: Running `npm list split` should list all installed locations - even sub-dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my specific situation is that I was using `npm ls --depth=0` and didn't see `split` in it, but it's a dependency several levels deep inside the project, and `require` obviously is able to find it that way, and it was simply a coincidence (no manual install of `split` ended up being necessary)